# Angular filter specific field based upon select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to filter an `ng-repeat` that I have based upon a select and an input. If the input is set to `all` then filter on all fields, if it is set to a different select value then only filter on that field.

I have HTML that looks like this

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" id="searchBox" ng-model="searchText">

<select class="form-control" id="searchType" name="searchType" ng-model="searchType">
  <option value="all">All Fields</option>
  <option value="locationCode">Location Code</option>
</select>

<!-- more code -->

<tr ng-if="!searchAll" ng-repeat="location in locations | filter:{searchType: searchText}" ts-repeat>
<tr ng-if="searchAll" ng-repeat="location in locations | filter:searchText" ts-repeat>
```

I'm also updating `$location.search()` when either the select or input are changed, but this should be the relevant part of my controller:

```
$scope.$watch('searchType', function(value) {
  $location.search('t', value).replace();
  $scope.searchAll = $scope.searchType === 'all';
});
```

My filter works properly when `all` is selected, but shows no data at all when another value is selected. However, it does work if I hardcode one of the field values in `searchType` in the first `ng-if`.

What obvious thing am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the left hand value in an object can be variable. So when you do this

```
location in locations | filter:{searchType: searchText}
```

You a expecting the filter to find a property named `searchType` instead of `locationCode`

I think the simplest fix would be to create a filter function in the controller and handle the switch in there.

Something like :

```
$scope.propertyFilter = function(item) {
  return item[$scope.searchType] == $scope.searchText;
}
```

And then inside your template

```
location in locations | filter:propertyFilter
```

I also wonder if treating the object as a string might work. Something like this :

```
location in locations | filter:{{"{" + searchType + ":" + searchText + "}"}}
```

Comment: I'm still trying to get this to work like I want, but I do believe your first solution has me headed in the right direction.